# VBA WORD. Поиск фразы в тексте

Tags: vba, ms-word, макросы

Как проверить вхождение фразы "студент Стек Оверфловов" в текст документа? После "студент" может быть от 1+ пробелов. Вылетает WORD на строке `.Find.Execute`.

```
Sub CheckForWildcardsText()
Dim searchPattern As String
Dim foundRange As Range

' Критерий
searchPattern = "студент {1;}Стек Оверфловов"


Set foundRange = ActiveDocument.Content

foundRange.Find.ClearFormatting

With foundRange.Find
    .text = searchPattern
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With


If foundRange.Find.Execute Then  ' Здесь WORD вылетает  
    MsgBox "Text with wildcards found: " & foundRange.text
Else
    MsgBox "Text with wildcards not found."
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Если же прописать замену, то все работает и Word не вылетает `foundRange.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, ReplaceWith:=replacement` Но ведь задание "найти", а не "заменить"

Comment: Попробуйте поиграть атрибутом ``foundRange.LanguageId``. Можно присвоить значение wdRussian (1049 Русский язык).

Comment: `.LanguageID` не помог. Вылетает на `.Execute` если в тексте есть совпадение.

Comment: `Dim foundRange As Range ..... Set foundRange = ActiveDocument.Content` меняем на `Dim foundRange As Object.....ActiveDocument.Select: Set foundRange = Selection` и будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема связана с азбукой (попробуйте напр. с английским текстом и ваш код будет работать).

В самом документе азбука кодируется иначе как в коде VBA. Чтобы это обойти

1. напишите ваше регулярное выражение `студент {1;}Стек Оверфловов` временно прямо в документ,
2. скопируйте его в клипборд (после того вы можете его удалить),
3. вставите его в ваш код (вместо `студент {1;}Стек Оверфловов`)

В вашем коде вы увидите

```
' Criteria
searchPattern = "??????? {1;}???? ??????????"
```

но все равно, ваш код будет работать.